# How does output buffer work inside a function?

Tags: php, output-buffering

I can't understand how output buffer inside function works

**File: template.html.php**

```
<p><?=$var1?></p>
<p><?=$var2?></p>
```

**File: layout.html.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$output?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**File: index.php**

```
function loadTemplate(){
  $var2 = 'two';
  ob_start();
  include 'template.html.php';
  return ob_get_clean();
}

$var1 = 'one';
$output = loadTemplate();
include 'layout.html.php';
```

When `$output` echoes it has not access to `$var2` because it was inside function and no longer exists. If `$var2` is accessed inside
the function, `$var1` should be `undefined` because it is not inside the function.
I can't understand what is really happening.

How is that working?

Comment: Ignore output buffer completely, that is an artifact of PHP's direct connection to the HTTP stream/whatever and is a red-herring. Instead, you just want to look into [PHP variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If you run the code with full errors/warnings enabled (which you should always do during development), you'll find that `$var1` actually doesn't exist in the scope because it is function-bound

Comment: @Code-Lover I do get "Undefined variable: var1" in my output when running your code. Don't you?